# Generate create table DDL from View

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I have a read access only oracle db that exposes Views for me to consume and I want to have local db where I insert the above data. To do that I need to generate create table DDL based on a views and I've found no way to do this.
To clarify I've used
`SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl('VIEW','table','schema') FROM dual` 
The result of that statement is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "SCHEMA"."VIEW_NAME" ("ID","NAME") AS 
SELECT * FROM SQUARE S
JOIN SHAPE SH ON( S.ID==SH.ID)
```

where what I want to generate is

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
    ID NUMBER,
    NAME VARCHER2(100),
```

Also I can't just run

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
  AS (SELECT * FROM view WHERE 1=2);
```

As the db I can read I can't create tables in.
Is there any tool that allows to run this with 2 db connections ? would that work?

EDIT: For those that can't figure how to do the database Link here is a garbage throwaway script that worked for me

```
 DECLARE
    starting boolean := TRUE;

    r_owner varchar2(30) := '$1';

    r_table_name varchar2(30) := '';

BEGIN
    
    FOR v IN ( --views from a owner
        SELECT
            VIEW_NAME 
        FROM
            all_views
        WHERE owner = r_owner)
    LOOP 
        
        r_table_name:= v.view_name;
        
        dbms_output.put_line('create table ' || r_owner || '.' || r_table_name || '(');
        
        starting := TRUE;
        FOR r IN ( -- columns from table
            SELECT
                column_name,
                data_type,
                data_length,
                data_precision,
                nullable
            FROM
                all_tab_columns
            WHERE
                table_name = upper(r_table_name)
                AND owner = upper(r_owner)
            ORDER BY column_id)
        LOOP
            
            IF starting THEN 
                starting := FALSE;
            ELSE 
                dbms_output.put_line(',');
            END IF;
        
            IF r.data_type = 'NUMBER' THEN
                IF r.data_length = 22 THEN
                    dbms_output.put('    '|| r.column_name || ' NUMBER');
                ELSE
                    dbms_output.put('    '|| r.column_name || ' NUMBER(' || r.data_length || ')');
                END IF;
            ELSIF r.data_type = 'FLOAT' THEN 
                dbms_output.put('    '|| r.column_name || ' FLOAT(' || r.data_precision || ')');
            ELSIF instr(r.data_type, 'CHAR') >0 then
                dbms_output.put('    '|| r.column_name||' '||r.data_type||'('||r.data_length||')');
            ELSE 
                dbms_output.put('    '|| r.column_name || ' ' || r.data_type);
            END IF;
        
            
            IF r.nullable = 'N' THEN 
                dbms_output.put(' NOT NULL');
            END IF;
            
            END LOOP;
            
            dbms_output.put_line('');
            dbms_output.put_line(' ); ');
            dbms_output.put_line('');

        END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your local db, create a link to the 'read only' db:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK READONLY_DB 
CONNECT TO scott IDENTIFIED BY tiger 
USING 'readonlydb';
```

Note, the USING 'readonbly' is referencing a tnsnames.ora entry for your readonly database.  Substitute 'readonlydb' with the appropriate, correct value.

Then, with the db link created:

```
create table my_table as select * from readonly_table@readonly_db;
```

Where:

- 'readonly_table' represents the name of the table at the readonly database
- 'readonly_db'  is the name of the database link you created in the first step.